# Generating Pretend Website Browsing Traffic

Tags: browsing, traffic, spoofing

I need to automate simple HTTP(s) web browsing traffic, visiting a variety of random sites. Current off-the-shelf solutions I have found are designed for increasing view counters or website testing.

There are two use cases, both of which are for targeted cyber crime defense strategy:

1. needle in a haystack style masking of actual user browsing
2. luring attackers of a corrupt communications company into the honeypot

Does anyone know any ready made solutions, or do I need to program one up from scratch?

Comment: this may be of some limited use: http://cs.nyu.edu/trackmenot/

Comment: @frank-thomas thanks for that - it's about 90% there and easier to extend than write from scratch